# QGIS Difference Tool Returns Empty Layer

Tags: qgis

I have two polygon layers. These layers are named Larger_Shapefile.shp and Smaller_shapefile.shp and can be downloaded from the following Onedrive link:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!ApH0MzZnZ2V4jJ5ZV8krxS1ekmSDwg

I'd like to create a new layer which is the "Difference" between the Larger_shapefile.shp and the Smaller_shapefile.shp. I use the Difference tool in QGIS. But the output of the tool is an empty layer. Do you have any idea what is going wrong here? Is there a different way to create the difference?

I understand that these shapefiles have 'Invalid Geometry'. But even selecting "Ignore invalid input features" option does not help and the returned difference layer is still empty.

Comment: For this situation you need to fix the original geometries using the following geo-tool: "Analysis Tools"->"Vector-Geometry"->"Fix Geometries"...

Comment: @CyrilMikhalchenko Thank you so much! After fixing the geometries, I can now get the difference perfectly!

Comment: You're always welcome :-)...